# ¿como cambiar el color de un div o una sección de acuerdo a un radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Buen dia, tengo este codigo:

Tipo de solicitud

```
                    <input type="radio" name="Capex/Opex" value="Mantenimiento" id="mantenimiento"onclick="document.getElementById('cual').setAttribute('readonly', true), document.getElementById('necesidad').setAttribute('disabled', true), document.getElementById('fecha2').setAttribute('readonly', true), document.getElementById('CeCo').removeAttribute('readonly')"/>
                    <label class="nombreRadio" for="mantenimiento">Mantenimiento  </label>
                    
                    <input type="radio" name="Capex/Opex" value="Novedad" id="novedad"onclick="document.getElementById('CeCo').setAttribute('readonly',true), document.getElementById('RN').removeAttribute('readonly')"  />
                    <label class="nombreRadio" for="novedad">Novedad</label>
```

Lo que busco es que cuando se seleccione algun input de estos se cambie de color lo que tengo dentro de un div:

**Mantenimiento:**

```
                    <label for="accion">Acción</label>
                    <br>
                    <textarea class="texto" type="text" id="accion" name="Acción" placeholder="Escriba aquí" required> </textarea>
                    <br>

                    <label class="pregunta" for="fechainicio1">Fecha de inicio</label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="texto" type="date" id="fechainicio1" name="Fecha de inicio" required />
                    <br>

                    <label for="fechacierre">Fecha de cierre</label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="texto" type="date" id="fechacierre" name="Fecha de cierre" required />
                </div>
```

si selecciono mantenimiento, que se ponga en un color esta seccion de mantenimiento, si selecciono novedad que se ponga en un color la seccion de novedad que es parecida al codigo anterior. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes modificar estilos de los distintos elementos del DOM de la siguiente forma:

```html
<input type="radio" name="Capex/Opex" value="Mantenimiento" id="mantenimiento"onclick="
document.getElementById('seccion-mantenimiento').style.background = 'green',
document.getElementById('seccion-novedad').style.background = 'white'"/>
                    <label class="nombreRadio" for="mantenimiento">Mantenimiento  </label>
                    
<input type="radio" name="Capex/Opex" value="Novedad" id="novedad"onclick="
document.getElementById('seccion-novedad').style.background = 'green',
document.getElementById('seccion-mantenimiento').style.background = 'white'"  />
                    <label class="nombreRadio" for="novedad">Novedad</label>
                    

<div id="seccion-mantenimiento">
<p> Esta es la sección de mantenimiento</p>
</div>

<div id="seccion-novedad">
<p> Esta es la sección de novedad</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias compañero!